# How to check if a string ends with punctuation in php?

Tags: php, regex

I am parsing some text line by line and if a given line ends with any punctuation or a number I'd like to have a boolean return true.

Is regex the best way or should I iterate with an array of chars to match?  Feels like the array would be far too big and costly...

Could someone help me with the regex if that is indeed a good way?

```
function ends_with_punctuation_or_num($string){
   // check if the string ends with punctuation or a number
    if (/* TODO */)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: If you check a boolean expression in a method, never return `true` or `false` in separate branches. Simply `return (expression)` and omit the `if..else` altogether.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Put this into your if-check:

```
preg_match("/[0-9.!?,;:]$/", $string)
```

That will match a digit, or any of the given punctuation characters right before the end of the string (`$`). Add any other punctuation characters you want to regard as a match into the character class (the square brackets).

Comment: Because he specified digit or punctuation. No spaces or anything. So I thought he would rather explicitly say which characters to match.

Comment: OK I'll give you that, this does follow the request exactly. I suspect that "non-alpha character" is what the OP really wants, but that would be for him to say. +1

Comment: @m.buettner this awesome, how would I also include '[', ']', '<', '>'

Comment: add `<` and `>` as they are, but escape the square brackets: `preg_match("/[0-9.!?,;:<>\[\]]$/", $string)`

Comment: You are all awesome, thanks so much both this solution and @DaveRandom's will work!

Comment: @dcoffey3296 Be aware that they do different things. Mine asserts that the last character is not in the blacklist `a-z`, m.buettner's asserts that it is in the whitelist `0-9.!?,;:`. Make sure you know exactly what you want to determine.

Comment: BTW: You don't even need if/else, simply "return preg_match(/*regex*/)==1; "

Answer (score 5):

The unicode property for punctuation is `\p{P}` or `\p{Punctuation}` for a number it's `\pN`.

In php you can use:

```
preg_match('/[\p{P}\p{N}]$/u', $string);
```

This will return true if the string ends with a punctuation or a digit.

Have a look at [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

Comment: @dcoffey3296: if you want to make it unicode- and i18n-save (e.g. Arabic), you should use this one!

Comment: It returns int 1 for true, and 0 for false. FYI.

Answer (score 1):

`echo substr("abcdef", -1);    // returns "f"`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use **substr function** or for utf-8 **mb_substr**

```
$last = substr($string, -1);

if($last == '.' OR is_numeric($last)) {]
```

But if you use UTF8 string i recommend you to use it like this

```
mb_internal_encoding('utf-8');
$last = mb_substr($string, -1);
if($last == '.' OR is_numeric($last)) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'd use a regex to do this. It's just personal preference, but a regex seems unnecessary and less readable (it's also slower, but that probably doesn't matter here). I'd rather drop whatever chars I'm looking for into a string and compare:

```
$chars = '.,;\'"0123456789';
$last = substr($string, -1);

if(strpbrk($last, $chars) !== false) {}
```

Obviously, use `mb_substring()` instead for Unicode.

Could also use `is_numeric()` instead of putting digits in the string. But I find this simpler, more readable, and easier to modify later.

Comment: Reasonable approach.  just change _strpos($chars, $last)_ to _strpbrk($last, $chars)_.